# Use awk to get things between two line

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Question 1:

I can use `awk` to get lines between two different keywords like this

```
$cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '/1/,/5/{print}' file.txt

$ cat file.txt 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
q
```

the output is:

```
$ sh -x test1.sh 
+ awk '/1/,/5/{print}' file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
1
q
```

How can I only get "1 2 3 4 5" ? Do not use `grep -B`、`grep -A` and `sed`

Question 2:
How can I get "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1" between two same keyword '1'?Do not use `grep -B`、`grep -A` and `sed` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the exit.

```
$ awk '/1/,/5/{print}$0==5{exit}' file.txt

$ awk '$1==1{a++}a>=2{print;exit}a{print}' file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
```

$1==1{a++}  --> if the 1st field value is 1, then increase the value of variable a

a>=2{print;exit}  --> if the value of a is greater than or equal to 2, then print the current line and exit (no further processing of file)

a{print} --> if value of a is not zero, then print the line

Comment: Thank you.@Kamaraj.  But can you explain the second sentence for me?

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: So the value of variable a at the beginning is 1?@Kamaraj

Comment: when the first field value is 1, then a value will become 1

Comment: But if 1 in file.txt change to b, and I want to get lines between two lines b,how I must do?

Comment: $1~/b/ or $1=="b"

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the right tool for this job. I don't really see why you shouldn't use it.  If this is a home assignment, please consider filing a complaint to the teacher.

```
$ sed -n -e '/^1/,/^5/p' -e '/^5/q' file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```

The `sed` commands will print (`p`) all lines between those that match `/^1/` and `/^5/`. It will also quit (`q`) if it finds a line matching `/^5/`.  The default output has been turned off (`-n`).

```
$ sed -n '/^[1-9]/p' file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
```